# Determine whether a polynomial is in an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I am trying determine if a polynomial, $f=x^3z - 2y^2$ is in the ideal $I=\left<xz-y, xy+2z^2, y-z\right>$?

I used maple to compute this. [my maple computation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ypvt.png)

Would this be correct? or have i got my basis wrong?

Comment: It seems quite likely to me that this is an XY problem with missing context. You seem to not trust the maple computation (which I agree with, by the way) because you think your definition of $I$ is wrong. But how could we possibly know if $I$ is "wrong" when we don't know where $I$ comes from?

Comment: @FShrike what do you mean by XY problem? I was not given any more context, only the polynomial f and the ideal I.

Comment: then how could you have "got the basis wrong"? If the basis is given in the question, that is. Or was $I$ given to you in another form? [XY](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Well... actually, whether the maple computation is correct would depend on the ambient ring $R$, I think. Is $R$ assumed to be the integers?